How do I remove the yellow debugger bar?
When running debugger in VS Code, a yellow bar appears that overlaps part of the interface. I do not know how to remove or move it...

When running the debugger in VS Code, a yellow bar appears that overlaps part of the interface. I do not know how to remove or move it...

That doesn't overlap. It is always there and it is names Status Bar. Just when debugging, it turns yellow (or another color depends on theme).
However you can hide it totally from View > Appearance > Show Status Bar, as answered in this question: How can I hide the status bar in VS Code?
